# Can someone explain what util.inherits does in more laymans terms?

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor

In the above documentation they talk about `util.inherits` which takes two constructors. I'm trying to wrap my brain around the code sample they provide. I know what a `Stream` is and I know what an `EventEmitter` is and I understand why you'd want to make a stream inherit from `EventEmitter` but I'm really confused about how they're doing it.

What exactly is `util.inherits` doing? And why to they create a new constructor that invokes `events.EventEmitter.call(this);`? What is the difference between this strange way of doing things and just creating a new instance of `EventEmitter` and setting it to `MyStream.prototype`?

Here is the code sample from the article for convenience:

```
var util = require("util");
var events = require("events");

function MyStream() {
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
}

util.inherits(MyStream, events.EventEmitter);

MyStream.prototype.write = function(data) {
    this.emit("data", data);
}

var stream = new MyStream();

console.log(stream instanceof events.EventEmitter); // true
console.log(MyStream.super_ === events.EventEmitter); // true

stream.on("data", function(data) {
    console.log('Received data: "' + data + '"');
})
stream.write("It works!"); // Received data: "It works!"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the implementation of `util.inherits` [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L572-L582):

```
exports.inherits = function(ctor, superCtor) {
  ctor.super_ = superCtor;
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
    constructor: {
      value: ctor,
      enumerable: false,
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
  });
};
```

It is essentially doing what you are describing (creating an instance of `events.EventEmitter.prototype` and setting that as the prototype of `MyStream`) along with attaching attaching `events.EventEmitter` to `MyStream.super_`.

The `events.EventEmitter.call(this);` invokes the `events.EventEmitter` constructor so that it gets executed whenever a new `MyStream` is created.  This is equivalent to calling `super()` in other languages like Java.

Comment: I am now clear on `util.inherits`, thank you. I still don't fully understand the call of the superConstructor. Wouldn't the prototype being set to a new instance of the superConstructor be enough?

Comment: @AlexFord: Setting the prototype just means instances of `MyStream` will inherit functions from `EventEmitter.prototype`.  The `EventEmitter` constructor does not automatically get called when `new MyStream()` is called.

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem to jive with what the text says. *"The prototype of `constructor` will be set to a new object created from `superConstructor`."* Doesn't that mean that `MyStream`'s prototype is set to an instance of `EventEmitter` rather than just `EventEmitter.prototype`? If so, doesn't that also mean that `MyStream` would inherit anything the `EventEmitter` constructor added to the instance as it was being created? I'm not saying you're wrong; just trying to understand :)

Comment: I think I'm getting lost trying to figure out what is going on with `Object.create` in the `inherits` function code you posted. I do think you're right and that the text in the documentation is wrong. I just don't fully understand why this is done this way. Maybe I just don't fully understand the usefulness of `Object.create` and what it's doing? Looks like it's taking the prototype of `EventEmitter` and adding a `constructor` property to it (not sure what that does) and then assigning that to `MyStream.prototype`. So it's just the same proto as `EventEmitter` with a `constructor` property?

Comment: I guess that then makes sense to invoke the `EventEmitter` constructor on `this` within `MyStream`'s constructor. I guess here's the two things I'm confused about: 1. Why not create a new instance of `EventEmitter` and assign that to `MyStream.prototype`? 2. Why does `util.inherits` add a `constructor` property to the new prototype, what does it do?

Comment: see this example https://github.com/dacosta-rafael/node-util.inherits/blob/master/app2.js

Answer (score 8):

```
var util = require('util');

function Person() {
    this.firstname = 'John';
    this.lastname = 'Doe';
}

Person.prototype.greet = function() {
    console.log('Hello ' + this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname);
}

function Policeman() {
    Person.call(this);
    this.badgenumber = '1234';
}

util.inherits(Policeman, Person);
var officer = new Policeman();
officer.greet();
```